# How to print out a markdown file on the console using node.js?

Tags: node.js, markdown

I have a README.md (markdown syntax) that I want to print out to the console using node.js.

Is this possible?

Comment: first off, why do you wish to print to the console? and what do you wish to print: html or markdown (or ascii or manpage etc.)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First install markdown-js (https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)

```
$ npm install markdown-js
```

Then make a javascript:

```
var markdown = require("markdown-js");
var fs = require("fs");

var str = fs.readFileSync("filename.md", "utf8");

var result = markdown.makeHtml(str);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: -1 for recommending `readFileSync`. Please use asynchronous commands.

Comment: for scripts that exit after the first tic async is pointless. It's not like the Sync is inside a response handler.

Comment: +1 agreed, for one-offs like this, async offers nothing but complexity.

Comment: Of course you should always write async if its a server/service etc, but that was not the nature of the question - and might* have taken away the main point.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -g marky-markdown
marky-markdown input.md > output.html
cat output.html
```

[npmjs](https://npmjs.org) display pages use Maruku markdown.  If you want to see how they will be displayed use the npm package [marky-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marky-markdown) as this is what [npmjs](https://npmjs.org) uses.  A full description is available on their [blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/109508231330/nicely-presented-markup).