# Difference between Github and npm markdown

Tags: github, npm, markdown

I have an Node package up on Github (https://github.com/jrootham/argument-spec) and npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/argument-spec).  There is a specification table where the first cell contains the word 'undefined'.  It shows up fine on Github but is blank on npm.  Anybody have any idea what is going on.  I searched for docs on npm markdown but none appeared.

Answer (score 1):

If npm readme html pages are generated (as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6110953/6309)) with [**`evilstreak/markdown-js`**](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js), then you have some [table examples](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/tree/master/test/features/tables), like [this one](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/blob/master/test/features/tables/simple_leading.text):

```
| First Header | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content 1 | Content 2 |
| Content 3 | Content 4 |
```

There is [issue 230](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/issues/230) discussing about the proper supoprt for table with this package, but it should be able to render most tables correctly.

In your case, see if adding delimiters change anything:

```
####Specification meanings

|Specification|Valid argument|
-----------|----------
|undefined|anything|
|''|string|
```

---

The [PR (Pull Request 480](https://github.com/npm/newww/pull/480) mentions:

> This updates newww to use **[`marky-markdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marky-markdown)** to process readme content. Highlights include:
>
> - Human-readable code!
> - Lots of tests
> - Explicit HTML content policy with sanitize-html
> - Server-side syntax highlighting
> - Gravatar URL cleanup
> - GitHub relative link cleanup
> - Better tagging of badge elements
> - Forward-looking CDN image support

That project in turn uses [**`markdown-it`**](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it), which has a [few issues around table](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/search?q=table&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: No change.  Any idea how to figure out which markdown npm uses?  
I also just noticed that npm is not interpreting the # strings as header levels.
Am I stuck with github npm icompatibilities?

Comment: @JimRootham some clues with https://github.com/npm/docs.npmjs.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=markdown and https://github.com/npm/newww/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=markdown

Comment: @JimRootham I have edited the answer with more specific references to the projects used by npm for processing the `README` pages.

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Rootham is right about the process `npm` uses to display markdown: they are filtered through marky-markdown and then displayed.  It looks like you've found a bug somewhere in this process; you should open an issue on the `npm` website repository, https://github.com/npm/newww

Comment: By "@Jim Rootham is right...", did you actually mean "@VonC is right"? Because I am the only one in this page to have suggested that `npm` uses `marky-markdow`.

Comment: Yup, sorry, associated the wrong name with the comment.  Sorry VonC