# markdown-js for nodejs : text.replace is not a function

Tags: node.js

I tried to use markdown-js as mentioned here:

[How to print out a markdown file on the console using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110953/how-to-print-out-a-markdown-file-on-the-console-using-node-js?lq=1)

```
    function readmarkdown (error, page) {

        if (error) {

            Response.writeHead(404);
            Response.write('Error');
            Response.end(); 

        } else {              

            Response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            var markdown = require("markdown-js");
            Response.write(markdown.makeHtml(page));
            Response.end(); 
        }      

    }   

    fs.readFile( __dirname + 'markdown.md', readmarkdown);
```

Why do I get this error:

```
text = text.replace(/¨/g, '¨T');

TypeError: text.replace is not a function
at makeHtml
```

Comment: Most likely because you didn't pass a string to the `makeHtml` method. You should include your code in the question.

Comment: Also, `markdown-js` has become abandoned, so you should migrate to [`markdown-it`](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) instead.

Comment: @Svenskunganka I updated with code

Comment: If you do `console.log(typeof page)` inside the `readmarkdown` function, what do you get? You might also want to read the file with `utf8` encoding: `fs.readFile(__dirname + 'markdown.md, 'utf8', readmarkdown)`

Comment: @Svenskunganka typeof gives object. Why ? According to doc it is a string https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Comment: Or a `Buffer`, which doesn't have a `replace` method. You can always make a string from a buffer with `buffer.toString()` though. I still think you should use `markdown-it` instead of `markdown-js` because `markdown-js` is abandoned and has a lot of bugs, and `markdown-it` is substantially faster.

Comment: @Svenskunganka thanks it works with tostring. I'll try markdown-it later. How do you know when it'll be a string or a buffer ?

Comment: If you set the encoding to `utf8` when reading the file as I previously showed in the comments, it will return a `String`. If you don't set an encoding it will return a `Buffer`. From the docs: *"If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned."*

Comment: @Svenskunganka thanks if you put your answer in a post I will mark it as right one.