# Cannot find module 'markdown-js'

Tags: node.js, markdown

I installed markdown-js module with

```
npm install markdown
```

and I can see markdown module in node_modules

within my current project folder which contains index.js

Still I got this error

> Cannot find module 'markdown-js'

for

```
let markdown = require("markdown-js");
```

How is this possible

Comment: Shouldn't it be `require ('markdown')` ? https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js#Usage

Comment: Closing as typo. You require the package by doing `require('packagename')`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let markdown = require("markdown")
```

Comment: It has worked in another program https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716173/markdown-js-for-nodejs-text-replace-is-not-a-function

Comment: there is a different module `markdown-js`. did you recently delete your `node_modules`?

Comment: OK seems there's a bunch of markdown library I don't even remember which one I used seems I used another one  :(